# .forEach that accepts multiple lines in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to loop through an array in flutter called, `cart` and I need to execute multiple lines, I couldn't figure out how to do it

```
`Map<int, dynamic> cart = {77 => "ABC", 110 => "XYZ"};
cart.forEach((K,V) => {
    print(K);
    print(V);
});`
```

Why this wouldn't work? I think I am missing a `function` somewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Map<int, dynamic> cart = {77 : "ABC", 110 : "XYZ"};
cart.forEach((k, v) {

  print("$k: $v");

});
```

Comment: I got this: "The type 'Map<int, dynamic> used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable"

Comment: Updated the Answer please try this

Comment: it is now underlining ".key" that we added, and it says "The getter 'key' isn't  defined for the class 'Map<int, dynamic>'

Comment: there is an issue with the map you need to you ":" instead of "=>"

Answer (score 2):

That's not an array, it's a [`Map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/Map-class.html). (Nitpick: Dart doesn't have arrays, only `List`s.)

Maps by themselves aren't iterable. You need to use the `keys`, `values`, or `entries` properties.

```dart
Map<int, dynamic> cart = {77: "ABC", 110: "XYZ"};

for (var key in cart.keys) {
  print(key);
  // Will print:
  // 77
  // 110
}

for (var value in cart.values) {
  print(value);
  // Will print: 
  // ABC
  // XYZ
}

for (var entry in cart.entries) {
  print(entry.key + ': ' + entry.value);
  // Will print:
  // 77: ABC
  // 110: XYZ
}
```

**EDIT:**

I just noticed the syntax you're using to create your map.

```
Map<int, dynamic> cart = {77 => "ABC", 110 => "XYZ"};
```

This isn't a valid `Map` literal. Instead of fat arrows `=>` you need a colon `:`.

```
Map<int, dynamic> cart = {77: "ABC", 110: "XYZ"};
```

What you had before was a weird way to create a `Set` of lambda functions, although the syntax there wasn't quite right either as A) the parameter list needs to be surrounded by parentheses and B) the parameter names can't start with a number. If your curious, this is how you would declare that:

```
Set<String Function(dynamic)> cart = {(_77) => "ABC", (_110) => "XYZ"};
```

But that probably doesn't have anything to do with your actual question though, just a bit of useless trivia. :P

Answer (score -1):

```
cart.forEach((element) => (){
    print('');
    print('');
})
```